# Can I Improve my website's Google rankings with a bot that searches for my site and clicks on it?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, ctr

I have started a new website that I want like to obtain worldwide traffic for. And ofcourse, a key element is how to improve my Google search engine rank.

I am considering to develop a bot that would Google the website's keywords and then keep scrolling/changing Google search page until it finds my website and clicks on it.

Is this a good way to improve my SEO? presumably, this would require revolving IPs from different countries, but assuming I could resolve that, Would this be worthwhile approach to improving my websites ranking.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way to improve SEO.  At best it is black hat.   Its a good way to get your site considered spammy when Google find out - and Google will find out.

(I can think of at least 5 technical flaws with your plan that I posit Google could pick up on and penalize you for)

Comment: Why do you think its blackhat? And can you name the technical flaws?I suppose alot of SEO methods are trying to leverage the system in a way to improve their rank.

Comment: I deliberately did not name the technical flaws for much the same reason I don't help people hack computers they don't control.  You can play "tick the boxes" at https://www.wordstream.com/black-hat-seo  to see why I think your strategy qualifies.  If you want to increase your SEO, think about EAT - https://ahrefs.com/blog/eat-seo/